# Библиотеки для работы с COM-портом

Tags: java, com-порт, поиск-библиотек

Нужно сделать примитивное общение с устройством через **COM-порт**. Какие есть вообще библиотеки для этого? Что ни нахожу в гугле - то пизанские башни с установленным монитором и кучей критики. Плюс практически все мануалы старые, как мой ПК.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете легко считывать данные из порта `usb` с помощью [jssc](https://github.com/scream3r/java-simple-serial-connector).

Пример чтения данных из usb:

```
import jssc.SerialPort;
import jssc.SerialPortEvent;
import jssc.SerialPortEventListener;
import jssc.SerialPortException;

public class Test {

    private static SerialPort serialPort;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Передаём в конструктор имя порта
        serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1");
        try {
            //Открываем порт
            serialPort.openPort();
            //Выставляем параметры
            serialPort.setParams(SerialPort.BAUDRATE_9600,
                                 SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                                 SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                                 SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
            //Включаем аппаратное управление потоком
            serialPort.setFlowControlMode(SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_RTSCTS_IN | 
                                          SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_RTSCTS_OUT);
            //Устанавливаем ивент лисенер и маску
            serialPort.addEventListener(new PortReader(), SerialPort.MASK_RXCHAR);
            //Отправляем запрос устройству
            serialPort.writeString("Get data");
        }
        catch (SerialPortException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }

    private static class PortReader implements SerialPortEventListener {

        public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
            if(event.isRXCHAR() && event.getEventValue() > 0){
                try {
                    //Получаем ответ от устройства, обрабатываем данные и т.д.
                    String data = serialPort.readString(event.getEventValue());
                    //И снова отправляем запрос
                    serialPort.writeString("Get data");
                }
                catch (SerialPortException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```